# Use liquibase insert based on select

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2, liquibase

How can the following SQL be translated into a liquibase changeset?

```
insert into u_gs(u_id, g_id)
select distinct u_id, 300 as g_id from u_gs WHERE groups_id IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

I have tried using

```
 <insert tableName="u_gs">
      <column name="g_id" value="306"/>
      <column name="u_id" valueComputed="( select distinct u_id from u_gs WHERE g_id IN ('1', '2', '3'))"/>
    </insert>
```

However then I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Scalar subquery contains more than one row; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.u_gs (g_id, u_id) VALUES ('306', (select u_id from u_gs WHERE groups_id IN ('1', '2', '3'))) -- ('306', (SELECT
    U_ID
FROM PUBLIC.U_GS
WHERE G_ID IN('1', '2', '3')))
```

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the SQL statement, are you able to run it locally in the SQL client, e.g Toad, Dbver, etc?